# Akka.NET Streams

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka.net-streams

How would you replay a web service request every ten seconds for ten times until it answers?

I've tried `RecoverWithRetries` and `InitialDelay`, but the first recovery immediately replays the web service call:

```cs
FromThirdOfContract().RecoverWithRetries(e =>
{
    return Source.FromTask(_third.GetThird(message.ContractIdLegacy)).InitialDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsbetween));
}, retry);
```

The first retry happens immediately instead of ten seconds later. In Akka, there's a `RestartSource` class; we don't have it in Akka.NET. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally played with `Source.Lazily()` with my source. It's working, it's not evaluated before the initial delay call. But I'm listening for any other ideas